# RabbitMQ - ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused

Tags: authentication, rabbitmq, message-queue

I'm using `rabbitmq-server` and fetch messages from it using a consumer written in Scala. This has been working like a charm but since I migrated my RabbitMQ server from a server to another, I get the following error when trying to connect to it:

```
com.rabbitmq.client.AuthenticationFailureException: ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.
```

In addition, the `rabbitmq-server` logs:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 18-Jul-2018::15:28:05 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.7107.0> (127.0.0.1:42632 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=ERROR REPORT==== 18-Jul-2018::15:28:05 ===
Error on AMQP connection <0.7107.0> (127.0.0.1:42632 -> 127.0.0.1:5672, state: starting):
PLAIN login refused: user 'my_personal_user' - invalid credentials

=INFO REPORT==== 18-Jul-2018::15:28:05 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.7107.0> (127.0.0.1:42632 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)
```

I went through every SO questions about authentication problems and found the following leads:

- My credentials are wrong
- I'm trying to connect with `guest` from
  remote
- My RabbitMQ version is not compatible with the consumer

All those leads did not help me. My crendetials are good, I'm not using `guest` to connect but a privileged user with full access and admin I created and my RabbitMQ version did not change through the migration.

NB: I migrated my RabbitMQ server from a separate server to the same as my consumer, so now the consumer is fetching from localhost. Don't know the consequences but I figured it could help you guys help me.

Comment: Try out your username (`my_personal_user`) and password using the `rabbitmqctl authenticate_user` command. Does that command succeed?

Comment: It does work yes, I successfully authenticate.

Comment: `curl -i -u user:password http://localhost:15672/api/whoami` works too.

Comment: Most likely there is an error in your application. Use Wireshark to view port `5672` and see what credentials your application is sending.

Comment: I use both a consumer written in Scala and a producer written in Node.js. Both work on my old server and both failed to authenticate on the new one. I suspect this is coming from RabbitMQ itself .. I’ll try to monitor the port 5672 to see what’s really happening, thanks for the tip.

Comment: It is coming from RabbitMQ in that it's denying access. Since `authenticate_user` and your `curl` command succeed, I can only guess that your application isn't sending exactly the correct username or password. Check the data byte-by-byte in your Wireshark capture. Finally, be sure you are connecting to the expected virtual host, and that the user has permissions for that vhost.

Answer (score 1):

So I just had a similar problem googled solutions, which is how I found this page. I didn't find a direct answer to my question, but I ended up discovering that rabbitmq has 2 different sets of rights to configure that don't exactly overlap with each other, in my case I had 0 rights for 1 set of rights and admin rights for the other set of rights. I wounder if you could be running into a similar scenario.

Seeing code will make the 2 sets of rights make more since, but first some background context:

My RMQ is hosted on Kubernetes where stuffs ephemeral, and I needed some usernames and passwords to ship preloaded with a fresh rabbitmq instance, well in Kubernetes there's an option to inject a preconfigured broker definition on first startup. (When I say broker definition I'm referring to that spot in the management Web GUI there's an option to import and export broker definitions AKA backup or replace your RMQ live configuration.)

Here's a shortened version of my config with sensitive stuff removed:

> ```
> {
>   "vhosts": [
>       {"name":"/"}
>   ],
>   "policies": [
>     { 
>       "name": "ha",
>       "vhost": "/",
>       "pattern": ".*",
>       "definition": { 
>         "ha-mode": "all",
>         "ha-sync-mode": "automatic",
>         "ha-sync-batch-size": 2
>       }
>     }
>   ],
>   "users": [
>     {
>       "name": "guest",
>       "password": "guest",
>       "tags": "management"
>     },
>     {
>       "name": "admin",
>       "password": "PASSWORD",
>       "tags": "administrator"
>     }
>   ],
>   "permissions": [
>     {
>       "user": "guest",
>       "vhost": "/",
>       "configure": "^$",
>       "write": "^$",
>       "read": "^$"
>     },
>     {
>       "user": "admin",
>       "vhost": "/",
>       "configure": ".*",
>       "write": ".*",
>       "read": ".*"
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

Ok so when I originally saw that tags attribute, I assumed o arbitrary value I'll put a self documenting tag there, and that was equivalent to "", which resulted in me having 0 rights to the web management GUI/REST API, while below I had all ".*" so that part had full admin rights. It was really confusing for me because (I was getting a false error message saying I was supplying invalid credentials, but the credentials were correct, I just didn't have access.)

If it's not that then there's also this configuration thing where guest gets limited to localhost access only by default, but you can override it.

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem, we were also facing with different tech stack. In our case tech stack was:

- RabbitMQ deployed in Kubernetes (AKS) using Bitnami package in HA mode
- Consumer and Producer created in microservice created using Java 8 with Spring Boot Framework using Apache Camel also running in same Kubernetes cluster

We verified below points:

- User and password are correct
- User associated with required VHOST
- Required permission given (administrator tag)
- User was able to login from RabbitMQ Web Console
- Connectivity on host and port was there from microservice Pod to RabbitMQ service (checked with various tools like telnet)
- All code and configuration was absolutely same (as there is same configuration in lower environment working correctly)

Was getting issue:

```
com.rabbitmq.client.AuthenticationFailureException: ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.
```

After much investigation and troubleshoot we found that, the size of username was larger than consumer API supported.
Example, we used username 'productionappuser'. This user was able to login in management web console but was failing from microservice.
We just changed the username to a new user with 8 characters and it started working.

This looks very weird as same user was able to login thus shared findings.

Comment: I got the same problem and I have to create new user with username less chars

Comment: create user with less chars worked ! @Sandeep Kumar

Answer (score 0):

mine was vhost set to "/abc" , it should be  "abc"

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this issue, please don't panic; the logs about "Plain Mechanism" are horribly misleading.

The solution is to just check your login credentials to see if they work. I spent an entire day searching how to set base64 credentials in my connection string to the broker.

After reading this page, I recheck my credentials only to find out the password had a typo.

Once I corrected this, the ugly misleading error just vanished.